# jQuery ajax POST request fired twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

The ajax `POST` request that I'm firing here is to insert a line of data into the database but into two separate tables. First, here is my jQuery code.

```
$(window).on 'add.playlist', (e, collection, callback) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    if window.Playlist.show_bucket_list()[0].id
      alert 'You have already made a Playlist with these videos.'
      return false
    if $('.add-playlist input').val().trim().length < 1
      alert 'Please make a name.'
      return false
    $.ajax
      url: '/playlist/add/new'
      method: 'post'
      async: false
      headers:
        Accept: 'application/json'
      data:
        playlist_name: $('.add-playlist input').val()
        data: JSON.stringify collection
      success: (d, s, x) ->
        console.log 'playlist add result: ', d
        if x.status isnt 200
          return 'Error'
      error: (x, s, d) ->
        console.log s, d
    return callback() if callback
  $ '.add-playlist form'
    .on 'submit', (e) ->
      after_adding_playlist = ->
        $ '.add-playlist-success'
          .removeClass 'hide'
          .addClass 'animated fadeInRight'
        setTimeout ->
          $('.add-playlist-success').addClass('animated fadeOutRight')
        , 2000
        setTimeout ->
          $('.add-playlist-success').addClass('hide').removeClass('animated fadeInRight fadeOutRight')
        , 3500
      $(window).trigger 'add.playlist', [window.Playlist.show_bucket_list(), after_adding_playlist]
```

Please note that I'm using CoffeeScript instead of Javascript. So I created an event called add.playlist and bound a callback function to it. And when the form is submitted, the event is triggered and `after_adding_playlist` function is fired when it's finished. However, I came to realize that every time I submit the form, the `POST` request is fired twice, first with all the data and second with no data, hence the server returning

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

because there is no JSON-formatted data to parse. Why is this happening? I've navigated through all of the similar questions on Stack Overflow but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: _"Why is this happening?"_ -> Because the form is submitted

Comment: the form `POST` will submit the data to the server. Do you need to do this **and** use an `AJAX` request?

Comment: @Daeyoung: Don't add error or warnings in code section add  > before your error text